# Can i be reborn having my father again?

Tags: theravada, personal-practice, karma, rebirth, western-philosophy

I lost my father when I was a kid. Can I be reborn with the same father?

I didn't know him well, as I was very young, but from people's words, he was a great man, and I'm dying to know him, to love and to feel him, and I'm dying that he can't take me down the aisle and watch me grow. Can I be with him again and fulfill my dream? Growing up and not having a father has caused me to have tons of troubles and complexes. What was this punishment for? Sometimes I think God didn't like me and I was too cruel in my life.

Comment: I've edited some of the grammar in your comment. Did I get anything wrong? Does the new version match your intentions in writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your father is dead. He's currently "someone else." He's not even your father right now. He's someone else. He won't necessarily be your father in the future if he's not now.

Like Frankk pointed out, there's a possibility that you'll all stick together, but not in the ways you currently are now. For all anyone knows, you could be *his* father in another life.

Answer (score 2):

Close Family and friends tend to rebirth into the same family and circle of friends again and again, just as those in the living world tend to like to stick to their close ones. Your father could potentially come back as a son, niece, nephew, children of close friends, a pet, etc. depending on his karma and merits.
Or if you and he both have strong positive karma, and he's in a godly realm, then humans with strong positive karma tend to have a bigger circle of friendly deities who lend a helping hand in this life. For example, family and friends of mine, and myself on occasion have experienced divine intervention preventing serious accidents. People who do lots of good attract benefactors, and seem to enjoy lots of good 'luck' in this life, and people who do lots of bad tend to have 'bad luck'. It's no accident.

Answer (score 0):

A person is a concept and doesn't exist. There exists only experience.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. I wonder if you could consider adding some more meat to your answer. There's something intriguing what you have written, and I think expanding more on that would develop that intrigue into something more substantial. Please read [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information about answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism Stack Exchange. The system flagged this as a low quality answer. This answer is too short and doesn't contain enough details. Also, if possible, it is preferred to cite sources to support the answer. Did you intend it to be a [comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) under the question? If not, please see [this guide](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.